# Rails 5 helpers to fetch tasks with different filters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I moved a lot of the loading/logic from my view to my controller, and it's working great but after I did this I now have several *very* similar helper methods in my controller.

What is a more efficient way of doing this? Is there? I assume `get_last_task_owed` and `get_first_task_owed` I would be able to do in the view by finding the `.first` and `.last` of the record respectively.

```
  def get_projects_owed
    current_user.projects.where('end_date > ?', Date.today).order(:start_date).pluck(:name, :start_date, :end_date)

  end

  def get_all_projects
    current_user.projects.order(:start_date).pluck(:name, :start_date, :end_date)
  end

  def get_all_tasks
    @project.tasks.order(:product, :task_start_date).pluck(:product, :task_name, :task_start_date, :task_end_date).to_json
  end

  def get_last_task_owed
    tasks = @project.tasks
    tasks.where('task_end_date >= ?', Date.today).order('task_end_date DESC').first.task_end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
  end

  def get_first_task_owed
    tasks = @project.tasks
    tasks.where('task_end_date >= ?', Date.today).order('task_end_date ASC').first.task_end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
  end

  helper_method :get_projects_owed
  helper_method :get_all_projects
  helper_method :get_clients_with_projects
  helper_method :get_all_tasks
  helper_method :get_last_task_owed
  helper_method :get_first_task_owed
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible improvement is using scopes:

```
def get_projects_owed
  current_user.projects.owed.recent_first.pluck(:name, :start_date, :end_date)
end

def get_all_projects
  current_user.projects.recent_first.pluck(:name, :start_date, :end_date)
end

def get_last_task_owed
  get_owed_tasks.last.task_end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
end

def get_first_task_owed
  get_owed_tasks.first.task_end_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
end

def get_owed_tasks
  tasks = @project.tasks
  tasks.owed.order('task_end_date DESC')
end

helper_method :get_owed_tasks


class Project
  scope :owed, -> { where('end_date > ?', Date.today) }
  scope :recent_first, -> { order(:start_date) }
end


class Task
  scope :owed, -> { where('task_end_date >= ?', Date.today) }
end
```